# Azure Function Produce 404 in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have 2 http triggered functions (let's call this A and B) in my azure function app that I am currently using in my azure logic app. I have created one logic app for each function as both are going to process differently.

Everytime I receive an email for each of the logic app, one azure logic app will call function A and another will call function B. However, the logic app starts to produce error 404 when I receive emails at the same timestamp.

Is there a way to let function app run both functions at the same time or wait till the one triggered finishes processing?

-edit-

This is the error that comes from my logic app when it is triggered. It runs when I trigger it manually but seems to create error when it is triggered on its own. I have used the function activity instead of the http activity and same issue.

[image]

Comment: What does the 404 refer to ? Are you processing files and deleted them once finished ? Could you add more details to your questions please ?

Comment: The 404 refers to cannot find the azure function in the azure logic app. I am fetching data from a blob and inserting into database. Not deleting anything

Comment: How do you call `Azure function`, could you please give a screenshot?

Comment: Do you have a blob binding so it can't find the blob ? are you deleting the blob once processed ?

Comment: Edited to include the screenshot. I am not deleting the blob once processed. I am getting an excel from my logic app and then creating a blob from that excel. This flow has been working for about 1 week or so and I'm suddenly getting this error.

Comment: @Kelly. Does your function support `get` requests? If only `post` requests are supported, this error will occur.

Comment: Yes it supports get requests

Comment: @Kelly. Is your url like this: `https://<functionapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function-name>`?

Comment: @FrankGong Yes it is

Comment: @Kelly. Have you tried setting the value of [Concurrency Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKPCr.png) to 1?

Comment: @FrankGong I have not tried that yet...where do I set that up?

Comment: It can be set [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma8H5.png).

Comment: @FrankGong thanks. Found out that it is likely because of the cold start of azure function.

Comment: @Kelly. In order to end this question, I posted an answer, which may help others.

Comment: Yes this is from a cold start - no a cold start is not supposed to automatically result in a 404 from azure.  A cold start is just supposed to result in a longer response time from your function. I have been seeing this behavior too recently (previously was working), and I think it is an issue on the Azure end.

 @FrankGong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the discussion in the `comment`, this problem may be caused by the cold start of `Azure function`.

Solution to prevent cold start of `Azure function`:

You can use `Premium plan` and set the number of `Always Ready Instances` to prevent cold start:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [Azure Functions Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal).